# plot dynamique reference lines with sas programme

Tags: sas

I'm trying to draw a variable with 3 reference lines calculated with user-selected parameters.

```
proc gplot data=DES;
   plot yn*n /vref= u-&r &r u+&r;
run;
```

r is choosen by the user

u is calculated

how can I assign the value directly to vref?

Comment: How is U calculated?  Where is it stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `VREF=` option a list of values. So `U` needs to be stored into a macro variable.  Then you can use `%EVAL()`, for integers, or `%SYSEVALF()`, for real values, to calculate the values to pass as the reference lines.

So your GPLOT code will look like:

```
proc gplot data=DES;
  plot yn*n /vref=( %sysevalf(&u-&r) &r %sysevalf(&u+&r) );
run;
```